# Not able to update the password in Rails 5 web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.2

In My Rails 5 Web App. I have installed Devise gem in it. When I wan to edit my password by clicking on link below but instead on going to the page for update password. Page get refreshed and It gives alert message you are already logged in .
I am using Below link in my Application:

```
<%= link_to('Edit Password' , edit_user_password_path)%>
```

Routes Files is as:

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

Please suggest me the changes to redirect to edit password page all other links like below are working.

```
<%= link_to('Edit Registration',edit_user_registration_path )%>
 <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
 <%= link_to('Edit Registration', edit_user_registration_path) %>
 <%= link_to('Edit Password', edit_user_password_path) %>
```

Comment: `edit_user_registration_path` allows you to edit your attributes including the password, isn't it what you want?

Comment: I just want to edit password only.